# call page in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a problem: I have created this page to load, and I wish to load at the end of loading the page game.html to start the game, but I can not do it, I immediately upload the game and not the upload page.

```
<html>

<style type="text/css">
#body {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: black;
    top:0;
    margin-left:-8;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;    
}

#loading {
    background: transparent;
    /* border: none !important;*/
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: solid 1px #0076a3;
    background: url("img/riempimento.jpg");
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
</style>
<div id="body">
<br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
<div id="loading">Caricamento...
</div>

<script>
    function finish() {
        document.getElementById("body").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("loading").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

window.location="game.html";
</script>
<body onload="finish();"></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is in changing page (window.location) during loading of script - not in onLoad function. Try to rewrite to something like this:

```
<script>
    function finish() {
        document.getElementById("body").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("loading").style.visibility = "hidden";
        window.location = "game.html";
    }
</script>
```

UPDATE. Html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        ... styles stay there
    </style>
    <script>
        function finish() {
            document.getElementById("body").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("loading").style.visibility = "hidden";
            window.location = "game.html";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="finish();">
    <div id="body">
        <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
        <div id="loading">Caricamento...</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so I do not load the page load quickly but game.html

Comment: @user3423280 I actually don't understand what you have written, but my idea is to change page to game.html in body onload function (which is "finish"). So that this start page will be loaded completely before page is changed

Comment: you practically have to create the page loading and loading charge me at the end of the game called game.html

Comment: @user3423280 I looked at your html code once more and figured out that it is also deadly incorrect. I will rewrite it as update of answer. But you still should understand what to you want to do and try to explain it. My thoughts now are that you need to browse to game.html page when this current page is loaded

Comment: yeah, pretty much I have a key to the star that its pressure connects me to the game page, I would like to do the so-called "loading ..." once the page has loaded, start the game .... my page called game.html

Comment: @user3423280 okay, but does my solution work for you?